sandbox checkout
when checkout with personal sandbox account the balance does not decrease and the balance of business sandbox account does not increased why despite the payment orderd is captured,
the personal account is in Egypt and Currency in EUR and Business account in US and currency is USD
i do not know why the balance in business sandbox account and the balance of pesonal sandbox account does not changed ?

Add an example capture id and response to your question. The balance of the business receiver account should increase.

"orderId":"01C101832M339332R",
Payment/capture?token=01C101832M339332R&PayerID=T9J35VKQM7SJU
this is you ask for ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Go to your list of Sandbox Accounts (log in), find the business account on the list, View/Edit settings on the right, scroll to the bottom, and look for the Payment Review setting. Verify that the slider is "Off".

